# What is causing this space between two elements and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: html, css

Here is a blueprint of what I am trying to do:

[image: screenshot of problem]

I am trying to get rid of this ugly space, but I am not sure where it is coming from.

HTML:

```
<div class="balance">
        <h3 id="balance"><img id="bitcoin" src=Images/bitcoin.png width="25px" height="25px"> Balance: Loading...</h3>
</div>

<div class="gamebox">
       <!--- Game box markup code --->
</div>
```

CSS for balance panel:

```
/* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: 10%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    float: right;
}
```

CSS for the main game panel:

```
/* Game box */
.gamebox{
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

What is causing the space? I'd like there to be not such a huge gap between the two panels.

Comment: try this in both elements: `margin: 20px 0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of this space between two side panel elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383369/how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-space-between-two-side-panel-elements)

Comment: Isn't this gap the rest of the 100% of the container width after its 50% was taken by the left panel and 30% — by the right panel (plus 80px for their paddings)?

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'margin' property in the css for balance box (and or for gamebox) to a lower number. If you still want to keep spaces up and down, specify the margins like this:

```
.balance {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;

   /*other code*/
    height: 10%;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    float: right;
}
```

Loosely said, the margin is the space around a div (or any object) in html

**EDIT**: I overlooked that you were floating the balance div to the right. In the css I specified both divs as inline block (so they go side by side) and the gamebox div to float to the left

```
 /* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: 10%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display: inline-block;
}

.gamebox{
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: alternative ( short version ): `margin: 20px 0` ( top/ bottom | left / right)

Comment: The space still remains

Comment: it seems even removing all margin code the space remains persistent

Comment: @webcod3rr Look at my edit. Does the new code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using box-sizing. Please check whether this works or not

HTML:

```
<div class="balance">
        <h3 id="balance"><img id="bitcoin" src=Images/bitcoin.png width="25px" height="25px"> Balance: Loading...</h3>
</div>

<div class="gamebox">
       <!--- Game box markup code --->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: box-border;
}
/* Balance box */
.balance{
    height: 10%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 30%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    float: right;
}

/* Game box */
.gamebox{
    height: auto;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: "smooth";
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try [`vertical-align:top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) instead of [`float:right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float)

By floating the `.balance` `<div>` to the right, you will have a gap between it and the `.gamebox` all the while there can be *i.e.* it will go as far right as it can.

If instead, the two elements are set to [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), the `.balance` can be simply aligned with the `top` of the `.gamebox`, and it will sit neatly and as closely as you like to the `.gamebox`.

See in the example below how the child `<div>`s of `.right` have their layout set by floating the second child `right`, whereas the child `<div>`s of `.left` are aligned using `vertical-align`.

```css
div[class] {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
div:not([class]) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.right div + div {
  float: right;
}
.left div + div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in css.

```
  .balance{
 height: 10%; 
margin-right : 100px; 
width: 30%; 
font-family: "smooth"; 
background-color: white; 
color: black;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
float: right;
```